# Remove attachment page for audio media type only

Tags: functions, attachments, wp-redirect

There is code below to redirect an attachment, but what about just for specific media types like audio or videos?

```
    function sar_attachment_redirect() {  
    global $post;
    if ( is_attachment() && isset($post->post_parent) && is_numeric($post->post_parent) && ($post->post_parent != 0) ) {
        wp_redirect(get_permalink($post->post_parent), 301); // permanent redirect to post/page where image or document was uploaded
        exit;
    } elseif ( is_attachment() && isset($post->post_parent) && is_numeric($post->post_parent) && ($post->post_parent < 1) ) {   // for some reason it doesnt works checking for 0, so checking lower than 1 instead...
        wp_redirect(get_bloginfo('wpurl'), 302); // temp redirect to home for image or document not associated to any post/page
        exit;       
}
}
add_action('template_redirect', 'sar_attachment_redirect',1);
```

Comment: get_post_mime_type() - https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_mime_type

Answer (score 1):

You must use this function `wp_check_filetype` to check what is your media type

```
$filetype = wp_check_filetype('image.jpg');
echo $filetype['ext']; // will output jpg
```

then you can have something like this

```
$file_url = wp_get_attachment_url( $file_id );
$filetype = wp_check_filetype( $file_url );

switch ($filetype) {
    case 'image/jpeg':
    case 'image/png':
    case 'image/gif':
      return   // do whatever you want 
      break;
    case 'video/mpeg':
    case 'video/mp4': 
    case 'video/quicktime':
      return // do whatever you want 
      break;
    case 'text/csv':
    case 'text/plain': 
    case 'text/xml':
      return // do whatever you want 
      break;
    default:
      return // do whatever you want 
  }
```

so in your function you can first check your attachment file type and when it's Video you can do your redirect code.

for more information:

1- https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_mime_type

2- https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_check_filetype

Hope it works for you.